# Reload django variable with ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I would like to change the value of a django variable with Ajax from template.

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    myvariable = 'initial'

    if request.POST:
        myvariable = 'success'
        return JsonResponse('OK', safe=False)

    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

**template.html**:

```
<div id="variable">{{myvariable}}</div>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="click here"/>

<script>
    $("#button").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({                      
            method:'POST' 
            success: function () { 
                $("#variable").load(location.href+" #variable>*",""); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The `POST` request is well received by Django and the value is change successfully however the value in the template don't change. Any idea ?
Strange things, I noticed after the POST request there is two GET request at the same time

```
    [05/Feb/2021 18:28:16] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 4
    [05/Feb/2021 18:28:16] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 24388
    [05/Feb/2021 18:28:16] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 24388
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t use `if request.POST` to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if `request.method == "POST"`(see [**HttpRequest.method**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)).

Also to change text you should use jQuery `text()` function instead `load()` in success function of AJAX.

I would also use `click()` event instead `submit()`.

See the following working example:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def myview(request):
    myvariable = 'initial'

    if request.method == "POST":
        myvariable = 'success'
        return JsonResponse('OK', safe=False)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**template.html**

```
<div id="variable">{{ myvariable }}</div>
<input id="button" type="button" value="click here"/>

<script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({                     
            method:'POST',
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#variable").text(data); 
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```